# Upgrade Failover Instance Google Cloud SQL Second Generation

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We created a second gen. Google Cloud SQL database with a failover replica and we've been looking into upgrading the CPU and memory to increase capacity. I've been able to change the tier of the first server by updating and saving the instance; however; when it comes to updating the failover the option to change tiers is greyed out

[image: Screenshot]

Is this intentional with the expectation that you delete and recreate the failover with a higher CPU/memory tier or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome. Please a) try to format your post nicely. There's a help topic about that when you're [edit]ing. Especially: show the image. b) do not write "thanks in advance" here.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you can use the API to change that: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/update